# Cannot install ruby gems on AIX 7.1 with ruby 2.4.5

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zlib, aix

I just compiled ruby from source on AIX 7.1. However, the following errors got logged during the make.

```
*** Following extensions failed to configure:
../../../ext/gdbm/extconf.rb:0: Failed to configure gdbm. It will not be installed.
../../../ext/readline/extconf.rb:0: Failed to configure readline. It will not be installed.
../../../ext/zlib/extconf.rb:0: Failed to configure zlib. It will not be installed.
*** Fix the problems, then remove these directories and try again if you want.
```

Now, when i try to install gems using gem install cool.io-1.5.3.gem, it gives the below error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

edit : gdbm, readline and zlib were all installed using rpm before compiling Ruby.

Comment: You should have a zlib-1.2.11 compiled from source.

Comment: I have installed the same using rpm and getting the error. Even rpm -qa shows that zlib, gdbm and readlines are installed. Is it mandatory to compile zlib from source? I

Comment: Well, I was wrong: turns out perzl does have a `libz-devel.rpm` package, so you don't have to install from source. http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Zlib

Comment: I had this installed before compiling ruby. But still got the error. Any other library/package that needs to be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the following RPM packages:

- `zlib-devel`
- `readline-devel`
- `gdbm-devel`

Available version numbers and direct download links are available on the [AIX Toolbox site](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/alpha.html).

After installing the development packages recompile Ruby and it should correctly compile those libraries, then retry your `gem install` command.

Comment: Thank you @anothermh for the help. It finally worked and I was able to install ruby gems.